# Can't Logon to Azure Windows Server 2016 VM

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, rdp

When using RDP to connect to my Azure Windows Server 2016 VM, I am able to connect and the blue loading screen appears briefly then turn black and the connection is broken. I have worked through all the troubleshoot suggestions of:

> After each troubleshooting step, try reconnecting to the VM:
>   1) Reset Remote Desktop configuration.
>   2) Check Network Security Group rules / Cloud Services endpoints.
>   3) Review VM console logs.
>   4) Reset the NIC for the VM.
>   5) Check the VM Resource Health.
>   6) Reset your VM password.
>   7) Restart your VM.
>   8) Redeploy your VM.

But nothing has worked.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: try upsizing the vm, so give it more compute power. it might work

Comment: It has not been resolved.

Comment: Can you give the screenshot where the connection was broken?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue? and have you tried the solutions below?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description. Many possible reasons may cause this black screen. Firstly You can try to upsize the VM via the Azure portal.

Also, I suggest checking the RDP client side.

- Use control+alt+end, then sign out to close the RDP session and launch another one.
- try to connect through Remote Desktop Manager which can resolve the same issue for someone.
- Known issue: [A black screen may appear while logon by using remote desktop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/555840)
- From Virtual Machine settings on the portal, find Diagnose and solve problems, follow the steps of SOLUTIONS TO COMMON PROBLEMS.

More references about [Black Screen after RDP](https://www.gfisk.com/remote-desktop-black-screen/)

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I can't do them because the connection breaks and the session closes.

Comment: @Gorata-OkomelaIT  Can you see the Azure VM is running from VM - Boot diagnostics on the portal? Have you tried to upsize the VM?

Comment: @Gorata-OkomelaIT, Can you RDP to another Azure VM which is in the same subnet with the problematic VM?

Comment: @Gorata-OkomelaIT  Is there any update on your side?

Comment: Microsoft have been looking into it for the past weeks. Without success. They have offered a new solution involving Hyper V which I am going to try as soon as I have some time. Sorry but no news for anyone else in the same position